# Repeat ForEach Loop (PHP) But Break

Tags: php, foreach

I am very confused on how I would go about this. If one of the "IF" statements is true at the start of a foreach loop I want the loop to just repeat without continuing. Yet I do not want to exit out of the loop completely. Example:

```
foreach ($postallionlist as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $postallionlist[0]) {
        Repeat Loop Here
    }
    else {
        Pass
    }

    If (??) {
        The loop will continue to here if the first if statement is false
    }
```

So basically what PHP word makes a foreach just start over again without exiting it.

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding exactly what you want, but it sounds like you want to use `continue;`. That will break out of the current iteration without exiting the loop entirely.

Comment: Why not put the "continue code" into the else?

Comment: Thank you @mtinsley! :D Continue is exactly what I wanted! :0